# Instagram Client Side Authentication using Python

Tags: python, bottle, urlparse

I am currently working on a bottle project and will be using Instagram api. I was hoping to use the client side authentication however I am having problems with the access token as it does not returns as a parameter.

I am making the request here:

> https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=redirect_uri&response_type=token&scope=basic+follower_list

The app is redirected to token page correctly and I can even see the token in the url. But when I try to parse it, it comes out empty.

```
@route('/oauth_callback')
def success_message():

token = request.GET.get("access_token")

print token.values()
return "success"
```

The token.values() returns an empty list.

ps: Keep in mind that when I try to do the same operation with server side authentication, I can successfully get the code and exchange it for a token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you make a query to Instagram api you must be receiving below response?

> http://your-redirect-uri#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

the part after **#** is termed as ***fragment*** and not query_string parameter and there is no way you can retrieve that information on Server side in Bottle.

To actually get fragments, `bottle.request.urlparts` is used

> **[urlparts](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.urlparts)**
>
> The url string as an urlparse.SplitResult tuple. The tuple
>   contains (scheme, host, path, query_string and fragment), but the
>   fragment is always empty because it is not visible to the server.

Use the SDK and preferably Server Side operations -> https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram

If you will to go with this approach, then managing a JavaScript which parses the access-token and then posts to your bottle api for your consumption which I don't recommend...

From https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/

> **Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication**
>
> If you are building an app that does not have a server component (a
>   purely javascript app, for instance), you will notice that it is
>   impossible to complete step three above to receive your access_token
>   without also having to store the secret on the client. You should
>   never pass or store your client_id secret onto a client. For these
>   situations there is the Implicit Authentication Flow.

Comment: thank you for this detailed answer. Thanks to Cambridge Analytica all these went to waste though :(